# How to avoid multitouch on a UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, interface-builder

I have a view that contains several `UIButtons`. In the Interface Builder, the box `Multiple Touch` is not checked for the view nor the buttons. Programmatically I never activate the multi touch. Though, I still can select (press) several button at the same time which obviously give so weird results.

Why does it act like this while I didn't activate Multi Touch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

apple multipleTouchEnabled document

> When set to YES, the receiver receives all touches associated with a
>   multi-touch sequence. When set to NO, the receiver receives only the
>   first touch event in a multi-touch sequence. The default value of this
>   property is NO.
>
> **Other views in the same window can still receive touch events when
>   this property is NO**. If you want this view to handle multi-touch
>   events exclusively, set the values of both this property and the
>   **exclusiveTouch** property to YES.

Answer (score 1):

Set for your buttons `exclusiveTouch = YES`

Answer (score 0):

You can stop the multiple button touches at the same time By the below line of code.

**SWIFT 3.0:**

```
tempButton.isExclusiveTouch = true
```

By default it's value is set to `false`.